# Are these 4 spaces defined by 4 different sets of standard basis the same space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

This figure is trying to illustrate 4 spaces defined by 4 different sets of [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis).

[image]

All four spaces are $\Bbb R^2$

All unit vectors $u \in \Bbb R^2$

Are these 4 spaces the same one?

Comment: All four are $\Bbb R^2$, arent't they?

Comment: yes, all unit vectors $u \in \Bbb R^2$

Comment: This question should not be tagged algebraic-geometry. Please read the tag description for an explanation and do not retag this with that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you take $n$ linear independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you will get a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is also clear that your sets of vectors are linear independent, as $$\lambda(\pm 1,0) + \mu (0, \pm 1) = (0,0)$$ clearly implies that $\lambda = \mu = 0$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so the answer to my question is "yes", those 4 spaces are the same one, right?

Comment: Yes. All of them are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the real plane.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is `sets of vectors are linear independent` a conduction from $\lambda(\pm 1,0) + \mu (0, \pm 1) = (0,0)$? if yes, why does $\lambda(\pm 1,0) + \mu (0, \pm 1) = (0,0)$ apply?

Comment: No, but from the fact that this equation is only sovable for $\lambda = \mu = 0$. Two vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are by definition called linear independent, if $\lambda v + \mu w = (0,0)$ is only solvable for $\lambda = \mu = 0$. This means you assume that equation holds and check which scalar work.