# Is $e_1 = [-1,0], \quad e_2 = [0,1]$ a standard basis for the Euclidean plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis)

> the standard basis for the Euclidean plane is formed by vectors
>
> $${\displaystyle \mathbf {e} _{x}=(1,0),\quad \mathbf {e}_{y}=(0,1)}$$

this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282322/are-these-4-spaces-defined-by-4-different-sets-of-standard-basis-the-same-space) is considering $e_1 = [-1,0];\quad e_2 = [0,1]$ as another standard basis, is this right?

Comment: The term "standard" basis is usually used for $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$. However $\Bbb{R}^2$ has infinitely many bases one of which is $\{(-1,0),(0,1)\}$.

Comment: I see standardbases as canonical choices of bases. This choice is canonical because vectors and coordinates relative to this base coincide.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it depends on the context in which the term "standard" is being used. As pointed out by @Anurag A, it is the base $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ that is usually referred to as standard, however, one may refer with the term "standard" to any base $\{u,v\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that $u,v$ are orthogonal an of length 1.

So, under the last view, the set $\{(-1,0),(0,1)\}$ is a standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Even so, I would prefer soma term more similar to "orthonormal" or so for such bases.